# Как присвоить домен из REG.RU в HEROKU

Tags: хостинг, домен, heroku

Запустил сервер на heroku. Настроил reg.ru и домен заработал только на домен с www. Попытался настроить так чтобы было домен был доступен без www, но никак не получается, так как heroku не выдает IP адреса и я не могу добавить A запись. Что делать?

Comment: [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain)

Comment: Удалось решить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию для направления на HEROKU добавляется CNAME-запись, которую можно создать только для субдомена. Чтобы настроить направление с адреса без www, нужно добавить в настройках домена запись типа ALIAS, которая будет направлена на HEROKU.

Comment: Не понятно как нужно настроить эту запись. Как должна вцелом выглядеть таблица? (изучил инструкцию, перепробовал разные варианты) У меня толко с www работает